# Chrome App - запись в файл

Tags: файлы, google-chrome, файловая-система, chrome-app

Делаю приложение-аудиоплеер для хрома. Хочу, чтобы после смены трека, его название записывалось в файл (стирая название предыдущего). У меня не получается записывать в файл. Пробовал вот это:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'saveFile', 
suggestedName: 'song.txt'}, 
 function(writableFileEntry) {
 writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
 writer.write(new Blob([songs[i].title],
{type: 'text/plain'})); 
 }, errorHandler);
});
```

но это просто открывает диалог сохранения в файл, а нужно, чтобы это происходило без участия пользователя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался во всем. Вот ссылки на видео и доки:

- https://youtu.be/h9YLMrCcvDc
- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage#sync-filesystem

Воспользовался "*syncFileSystem*" (файл сохраняется на Google Drive).
В файле конфигурации надо прописать вот это:

```
"permissions": [
  "...",
  "syncFileSystem"
]
```

А сам код записи выглядит так:

```
chrome.syncFileSystem.requestFileSystem(function (fs) {
   fs.root.getFile('test.txt', {create:true}, getEntryCallback, errorCallback);
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. если внешние ссылки «протухнут», ваш ответ станет бесполезен для базы знаний, которым является этот сайт.

Comment: ссылка ведет на официальную документацию. Если она протухнет, то сам вопрос, скорее всего, будет неактуален. Но я могу скопировать немного оттуда, если это важно